# Any way to update an invitation I sent on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, invitation

I'm wondering if there's any way to edit or update an invitation that I sent out. I mistyped the email address, and it doesn't look like there's any way to change it. Aside from wanting to make sure the invitation gets to the *right* person, I also want to make sure the invitation doesn't go to the *wrong* person.

Any way to do this, or will I have to use another invitation? Can an administrator remove the invitation and reset the number of available invitations I have left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way for you to do this -- once an invitation is sent, it's sent.

In your case, I deleted the extra invite manually so you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated!